# How to show numbers with comma separation in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I can't seem to find anything that would let me to easily show a Number in a label, textinput, etc. with comma separation.

like in a label, show number 123456.78 as 123,456.78

```
[Bindable]
private var num:Number = 123456.78;

<mx:Label text={num} />
```

Obviously I could just create a function, but is there a more simple way?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out ActionScript's **NumberFormatter** class. (`mx.formatters.NumberFormatter`)